# How to write a while loop using a sentinel value that's inside a do while loop?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, break

I'm having trouble writing a while loop for this code that has the gender as the Loop Control Variable (when you input the gender, it's in a do-while loop with specific conditions for it to be valid). also, i don't know what to do to be able to calculate the number and percent of candidates accepted.

```
     char gender;     //INPUT       Gender of candidate
     char genderOk;   //CALC & OUT  Checks validity of gender input
     int  height;     //INPUT       Height of candidate
     int  heightOk;   //CALC & OUT  Valid height range for candidate
     int  weight;     //INPUT       Weight of candidate
     int  weightOk;   //CALC & OUT  Valid weight range for candidates
     int  count;      //INPUT       Counter of the FOR loop
     int  candidates; //INPUT       Amount of candidates per test
     int  acceptCand; //CALC & OUT  # of candidates accepted per test
     int  acceptPerc; //CALC & OUT  % of candidates accepted per test


     // INPUT - describe input here

     cout << left;

     for(count = 1; count <= 3; count++)
     {
         cout << "TEST RUN #" << count << endl << endl << endl;

         cout << "Please enter candidate's information (enter 'X' to "
                 "exit).\n";

         gender = 'f';

         while(gender != 'X' || gender != 'x')
         {
         do
         {
             cout << "Gender: ";
             cin.get(gender);
             cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
             genderOk = gender != 'm' && gender != 'M' && gender != 'f'
                        && gender != 'F';
             if(genderOk)
             {
                 cout << "***** Invalid gender; please enter M or F "
                         "*****";
                 cout << endl;
             }
         }while(genderOk);

         do
         {
             cout << "Height: ";
             cin  >> (height);
             cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
             heightOk = height >= 24 && height <= 110;
             if(!heightOk)
             {
                 cout << "***** Invalid height; please enter a height "
                         "in inches between 24 and 110. *****";
                 cout << endl;
             }
         }while(!heightOk);

         do
         {
             cout << "Weight: ";
             cin  >> weight;
             cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
             weightOk = weight >= 50 && weight <= 1400;
             if(!weightOk)
             {
                 cout << "***** Invalid weight; please enter a weight "
                         "in lbs between 50 and 1400. *****";
                 cout << endl;
             }
         }while(!weightOk);


         if(gender == 'm' || gender == 'M')
         {
             heightOk = height >= 65  && height <= 80;
             weightOk = weight >= 130 && weight <= 250;

             if(heightOk && weightOk)
             {
                cout << RESULT << "ACCEPTED!\n\n\n\n";
             }
             else
             {
                if(!heightOk)
                {
                    if(!weightOk)
                    {
                        cout << RESULT << "rejected based on the "
                                          "HEIGHT and WEIGHT "
                                          "requirements."
                                          "\n\n\n\n";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << RESULT << "rejected based on the "
                                          "HEIGHT requirement."
                                          "\n\n\n\n";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!weightOk)
                    {
                        cout << RESULT << "rejected based on the "
                                          "WEIGHT requirement."
                                          "\n\n\n\n";
                    }
                }
             }
         }

         if(gender == 'f' || gender == 'F')
         {
            heightOk = height >= 62  && height <=75;
            weightOk = weight >= 110 && weight <= 185;

            if(heightOk && weightOk)
            {
                cout << RESULT << "ACCEPTED!\n\n\n\n";
            }
            else
            {
                if(!heightOk)
                {
                    if(!weightOk)
                    {
                        cout << RESULT << "rejected based on the "
                                          "HEIGHT and WEIGHT "
                                          "requirements.\n\n\n\n";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << RESULT << "rejected based on the"
                                          " HEIGHT requirement."
                                          "\n\n\n\n";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!weightOk)
                    {
                        cout << RESULT << "rejected based on the "
                                          "WEIGHT requirement."
                                          "\n\n\n\n";
                    }
                }
             }
         }
       }
     }
```

Comment: What is an "LCV"? And what is your specific question?  If you're having trouble with terminating a loop, post code (ideally minimal code) that shows the specific problem with a specific loop.

Comment: @Michael - I think brothermilk is new to programming, and it probably came from a book (that's where I found references to both lcv's and sentinels). I removed it because its not common for most C/C++/Java/... folks. I hope its not well known and its me who should know it :)

Comment: Your gender loop is preceded by the printed message `X to exit' but the testing does not test for 'X'...

Comment: I've found that "LCV" stands for "loop control variable".

Comment: sorry for being unclear, and yes i am new to programming (but i didn't learn "LCV" from a book). Thank you jonathan leffler for identifying the problem with my loop, but i still can't figure out how to test for 'X' inside the loop.

Comment: EDIT: I added in the while loop after the for loop.                                                                    i'm trying to make the test for a candidate multiple times in each test run.

Comment: ok i got some help at my school and i figured it out so i don't need anyone to answer this anymore because my code has changed a lot. thanks a lot for the comments though, they did identify some of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

### The while loop condition

To solve your problem with having the while loop condition, instead of checking what the input gender is in your main loop (this is actually never validated since the gender is assigned INSIDE the while loop), your control condition for your while loop can be a Boolean variable.

**This:**

```
bool isQuit = false;

while(!isQuit)
{
...
```

**Instead of:**

```
gender = 'f';

while(gender != 'X' || gender != 'x')
{
...
```

Then when the user can input a gender, you check for your quitting condition. (In this case, where `gender == 'X' || gender == 'x'`.)

```
if(gender == 'X' || gender == 'x') {
    isQuit = true;
    break;
} else if(genderOk) {
    cout << "***** Invalid gender; please enter M or F "
            "*****";
    cout << endl;
}
...
```

This will now break out of the `do..while` loop that is used to enter in the gender. All that needs to be added is a check to see if the user has chosen to quit the input loop or not.

```
// After the do..while loop for inputting gender
if(isQuit) {
    break;
}
```

Now the program will break out of the main while loop that we defined as having a loop condition of `while(!isQuit)`.

---

**Note:** The above will not break out of the `for` loop that runs three 'test runs'. To use the `isQuit` variable to quit out of the entire program, add the following code at the end of the `for` loop:

```
    if(isQuit) {
        break;
    }
} // END OF YOUR FOR LOOP
```

---

### Calculating candidates

To calculate the number of candidates, the number of accepted candidates and the percentage of accepted candidates, we need to keep track of two things.

1. Total number of candidates (Store value in `candidates`)
2. Total accepted candidates (Store value in `acceptCand`)

First we need to setup our variables correctly:

```
int    candidates; //INPUT       Amount of candidates per test
int    acceptCand; //CALC & OUT  # of candidates accepted per test
float  acceptPerc; //CALC & OUT  % of candidates accepted per test

candidates = 0;
acceptCand = 0;
acceptPerc = 0;
```

Whenever we reach a point where the user in not entering values, we assume that they have entered a valid candidate. Where you check what gender the candidate is, we can increase the candidate counter by 1.

```
if(gender == 'm' || gender == 'M') {
    candidates++;
...

if(gender == 'f' || gender == 'F') {
    candidates++;
...
```

Now that we are keeping track of the total number of candidates, we now need to know the number of ACCEPTED candidates. To do this, we increase the `acceptCand` variable by one each time a candidate is accepted.

```
if(heightOk && weightOk) {
    cout << "ACCEPTED!\n\n\n\n";
    acceptCand++;
}
```

And finally, to get the percentage of accepted candidates, you would do the following:

```
acceptPerc = (acceptCand / (float)candidates) * 100;
```

**Note:** `acceptPerc` is a `float` datatype so that we can use decimal places. We type cast the `candidates` variable to `float` so that we avoid integer division which would cause us to lose the decimal places and return only whole numbers.